# Using DFPBannerView in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, admob

I have a UICollectionView-based app, where you can tap on some of the tiles to go to a detail screen.

One of the tiles in the main app has a DFPBannerView view that shows an advertisement. Also, the detail screen has a smaller ad that is also a DFPBannerView.

Using Charles for profiling, what I see is that if I have the ad tile from the main screen created at any point(so scroll down to it and come back up), and then I drill into the detail screen, I will get two ad calls - one for the main screen and one for the detail, even though I explicitly see in code that I make only one.

Do I need to explicitly disable the ad somehow? If so, how? Everything I've found online says the SDK should take care of knowing when the ad is off screen for me, but it definitely doesn't seem to do so. I'm guessing this is happening because the ad is in a cell and the cell still lives, but I would think that's a fairly standard use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - I was passing a wrong width to the collection view layout class, which resulted in it thinking it can fit every single tile on the screen and so trying to render them all, including the ad one which was nowhere near being on the screen. Once that was fixed, the ad tile is no longer called until it is actually on the screen.

For what it's worth, the reason the width was wrong was because we referenced the width of the view's window during animation, and that window was nil, so the width was 0.